# How do you force Linux to detect a PS/2 device (e.g. mouse) on demand?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, hot-plug

I plugged in a PS/2 mouse while inside my Gnome desktop, but Linux doesn't recognize it.

Linux will only recognize the PS/2 mouse if it is plugged in before booting the machine (like a normal scenario).

In this case, I forgot to plug in the mouse, plugged it in when I got to the desktop, but realized that it doesn't work.

How do I detect PS/2 devices (my mouse) in real time so I don't have to reboot just to use a mouse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's just the way that the PS/2 port [works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_connector#Hotplugging). Unlike the USB, the PS/2 was not designed to be hot-plugged. If you need the hot-plugging capability, use a USB mouse. Otherwise, there is no guarantee that any solution will work consistently.

Comment: Are there any solutions to try that you know of, even if they may not be consistent?

Comment: Wait, after reading that Wiki page I guess not! hehe

Comment: @trusktr In my experience hotplugging a PS/2 mouse does work at least sometimes, but you have to notify X that it's there (I think `xinput` should be able to do it nowadays), or you have to tell X that you have a PS/2 mouse all the time (through an option in `xorg.conf`).

Answer (score 3):

There is anecdotal evidence that restarting the X Server or switching to a a different virtual terminal and back will cause PS/2 devices to be re-detected. I don't have a PS/2 device to test with at the moment though but it may just work.

Comment: I remember this sometimes working myself, but it was hit or miss.